# Spring Boot Social /connect/twitter vs /signin/twitter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-social, spring-security-oauth2

In my application I use Spring Boot Social and have two kind of urls, for example

```
/connect/twitter
```

and

```
/signin/twitter
```

Both of them work pretty similar.. what differences between these urls and which one should I use in order to authenticate\authorize user via social networks ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/signin/twitter` link should be used if you want to support a user logging in to your application with their twitter credentials.

The `/connect/twitter` link should be used if you have user authentication in the app and you just want users to connect their accounts (for example, a logged in user wants to connect their twitter account so they can see their followers etc)

See the following docs for reference:

[The "connect framework"](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#connectFramework)

[Sign in with service provider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#section_signin)